# How many grams of coffee to use with the George Howell Kalita Wave recipe?

Tags: pour-over

Ever since reading [this article from Prima Coffee](https://prima-coffee.com/learn/article/brewing-guides/comparing-kalita-wave-recipes/33005) comparing Kalita Wave recipes, I've been using the [George Howell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eftby.jpg) method. This recipe calls for 25-28g of coffee for 390g of water.

I find this to be fairly strong and I wonder why the recipe calls for this large amount of coffee. In the past I had done ~18g of coffee for my pour overs and thought it brewed a decent cup. I understand I'm free to change the amount per my own tastes/roast, but I want to know if there's specific reason why 25/390g seems to be the chosen ratio.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The given ratio is maybe a bit unusual - many sources for pour-over irrespective of the exact brand (Chemex, Hario,...) give [1:17](https://www.stumptowncoffee.com/blog/how-to-perfect-pour-over) or [60g per liter of water](https://www.theworktop.com/breakfast-brunch-recipes/how-to-make-pour-over-coffee/), which is 16.666. This seems to be the ballpark number for pour-over.

But is the Kalita different?
Your source calculates between 1:13.9 to 1:15.6. Interestingly, at least one [source](https://www.barista-passione.de/kalita-wave-dripper/) (in German, sorry) agrees with the ratio of 1:15.4 for the Kalita, yet [another](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=6x6YdlAmWLA) goes as low as 17.8.

> Conclusion, sort of:
>   **The ratio is opinion-based and a matter of taste.**

Of course it’s up to you to go significantly lower - you won’t be breaking any laws - and I will freely admit that I am a total whimp when it comes to coffee strength.